# how stop google calendars repeating events on additional calendars

Tags: macos, ical, google-calendar

This annoying behavior is that from time to time the additional calendars on my google account get repeated in the gmail account section and then in the Delegates section. I don't mind where they appear, at my account section or the Delegates,  but the problem is that they appear on both sections and the events get duplicated.

I uncheck the ones on the account section and check the ones on the Delegates and all look all right but then the calendars on the account section disappear and after a while they reappear and duplicate the events again. It's getting very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive research, it seems google knows about this, and apologizes and is working to fix it.

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/AWJSWllOt9Y/discussion

Comment: The better part of a decade later, I'm having the exact same issue and the above link to the forum post is broken.